# If I write a tic-tac-toe game that allows a programmer to change the algorithm or board pieces, is this a pluggable architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, pluggable

Say I make a tic-tac-toe game, and I use minimax to play a human/computer opponent. Some other guy comes along with a new decision making idea, expressed in code. If I create some way for him to use that algorithm instead of my stock one, without changing my original code, does that mean I have created pluggable software (isn't that new search routine a plugin)? Also, what if I make it so someone can write some way to change the pieces? Is that skinning or pluggable or both?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually distinguish between

- Loosely coupled architecture
- Plug-in/Add-in architecture

The difference is mostly in **cardinality**.

Let's say that you define the AI algorithm in an external library, and provide a way for a user to *replace* the algorithm without recompiling the original application, you have a loosely coupled application.

I've seen this done in shrink-wrapped enterprise software, where you can *change* the data access layer to talk to either SQL Server or Oracle. Still, it's one or the other.

A **Add-in Architecture**, on the other hand, is an architecture where the application may come with some default functionality out of the box, but it enables users to **add** *zero or many* different behaviours. Sometimes, there's an additional UI element that then lists the various options; an example would be various image processing filter plug-ins for Photoshop. I prefer the term **Add-in** over *Plug-in*, exactly because it defines the goal as being able to *add* behaviour to the application, instead of just replacing it. (Sure, *Plug-in* sort of signals that too, but I think *Add-in* is a bit more explicit.)

If you can change the way an application looks, we normally call this skinning, but you could argue that it's just a special case of plug-in architecture.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I made it so I could add an algorithm and not replace that's add-in.  I got it.